# Yield After Logical Operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, yield

Why does JavaScript not allow `yield` after a logical operator, like `&&` or `||`, or even `!`? For example, when I try:

```
function *generator(arg1, arg2) {
    yield arg1 && yield arg2;
}
```

in most browsers, as well as NodeJS, it throws an error about `yield` being a reserved word. The same happens when I use `yield*`. However, I can use 2 statements with `yield` (or `yield*`) back-to-back, even in the same line, like this:

```
function *generator(arg1, arg2) {
    yield arg1; yield arg2;
}
```

I understand that there is some difference between these 2 types of declarations, but they seem similar enough that both should be allowed. Why is this not the case? **Why is `yield` allowed directly after a semicolon, but not a logical operator?**

Comment: Is yield arg1 && yield arg2 what you are actually trying to do? Do you have a real world example?

Comment: I am using `koa` and `co-fs`. I was trying to find out if a folder exists and is a folder (i.e. `yield fs.exists(this.path) && fs.stat(this.path).isDirectory()`) as a substitute for `serve-static`. I am going to do it  slightly different way, but the investigation made me curious.

Comment: Hmm, fs.exists and fs.stat are both asynchronous. Not sure you can return them since they expect callbacks... but that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: With `co-fs` you can.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error.

Try:

```
function *g (a1,a2) {yield a1 && (yield a2);}
```

instead, in strict mode, of course. (I got this to work with babel.)

Comment: Which expression returned to `IteratorResult` ?  `a1` ? , `a2` ?

Comment: Oh so you are asking about semantics? My bad, I thought your question was why you got the error from the compiler (it sounded like a syntax question to me :\). As to what actually happens, that would be a separate question, I think.

Comment: Interesting that this is why my version fails. Also interesting is that if you turn this into an iterator then `next` it, you get the value of the second `yield`, which makes sense, but the iterator is not `done` yet. If you call `next` again, the iterator is done, and the value is `undefined`. I wonder where that `undefined` came from, and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

See [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)

> The `yield` keyword causes generator function execution to pause and the
>   value of the expression following the `yield` keyword is returned to the
>   generator's caller. It can be thought of as a generator-based version
>   of the `return` keyword.
>
> The `yield` keyword actually returns an `IteratorResult` object with two
>   properties, `value` and `done`. The `value` property is the result of
>   evaluating the `yield` expression, and `done` is a `Boolean` indicating
>   whether or not the generator function has fully completed.

Appear `yield` expects expression to follow `yield`.  `yield expression && yield` would return `yield` after `&&` , without reaching second expression; would not return an `IteratorResult` to generator function